# How to access a particular Maven repository from a project in GitLab?

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

I have different projects in GitLab and every project should have its own Maven repository (`<project>-releases`) in Nexus Repository Manager 3, like [GitLab Maven Repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/):

> With the GitLab Maven Repository, every project can have its own space to store its Maven artifacts.

Project's pipeline should deploy the artifacts to the Maven repository `<project>-releases`. (Other projects should not have access to this repository.)

I did following:

1. I created a hosted repository `<project>-releases` as described in [Hosting Maven Repositories](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/maven-repositories#MavenRepositories-HostingMavenRepositories).
2. I created a user `gitlab-<project>` as described in [Users](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/access-control/users). (Unfortunately the user needs unneccessary information for a application user like first name, last name and email.)

But I don't now how to give user `gitlab-<project>` access to repository `<project>-releases` only. I can't add repositories or (generated) privileges to a user.

Do I have to create also a role `<project>-deploy` for every repository? That would be really ugly. Is there at least a way to use one role with different repositories for different users like [JFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions)?